# Save Image GDI+ Error

Tags: vb.net, image, gdi+

I have researched this error and tweaked my code (below), but am still getting the "generic GDI+ error".  Any suggestions are much appreciated.

```
 Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

    mPictureBox.Image.Save("C:\Users\Public\Desktop\img.bmp")

End Sub

Private Sub btnOpen_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOpen.Click
    Dim dlg As New OpenFileDialog
    If dlg.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim ms As New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(dlg.FileName))
        Dim img As Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
        mPictureBox.Image = img
        origImage = mPictureBox.Image
        btnRotateRight.Enabled = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line exactly throws the exception?  There are 2 candidates for it (I assume the save click, but I assuming such things is rarely a good idea)

Comment: Sorry, yes, the save click throws the error.   Thanks.

Comment: Is the save path `C:\Users\Public\Desktop` valid?  An invalid path can throw that error.

Comment: It should be, but good catch. I will check that and post back. "Public" doesn't seem right to me. Thanks.

Comment: That was it TnTinMn!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this to force it to save as a bitmap:

```
    mPictureBox.Image.Save("C:\Users\Public\Desktop\img.bmp", Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: I did try that as well to no avail. Thanks!